# How to use "filter control" in google data studio report?

Tags: looker-studio, slicers

I have made a dashboard in data studio, but not able to insert filter control to the table.

Also is there any tool similar to "Slicers" used in Pivot Table in Data Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put filter controls on which only affect that table by grouping them.

See **What charts will the filter control affect?** here:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144?hl=en&ref_topic=6371413